# query of type "INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING" returns nothing

Tags: postgresql, upsert

The "returning" statement returns 0 rows, but I want the row that couldn't be inserted because of the conflict. Something I am missing there?

detail: table users_strategies got primary keys (id_strategy,id_account)

```
xsignalsbot=# select * from users_strategies;
 id | id_strategy | id_account | risk | active
----+-------------+------------+------+--------
  1 |           1 |         48 | 0.50 | t
  2 |           2 |         48 | 0.25 | f
(2 rows)

xsignalsbot=# insert into users_strategies (id_strategy,id_account) 
                 values (1,48) on conflict (id_strategy,id_account) do nothing
                    returning active,risk;
 active | risk
--------+------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: `returning` returns the values *that were inserted*, so this doesn't surprise me - no rows were inserted, so nothing to return. There might be a workaround, but in this simplified example I can't see why you'd need to - all it would do was return you values you already knew. My concern is that a workaround might be specific to the actual scenario you have, and not applicable to the simplified example, so it might be worth explaining a bit more why you need this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing DO NOTHING to UPDATE SET statement (not modifying the final result) gives the results wanted:

```
xsignalsbot=# insert into users_strategies (id_strategy,id_account) 
                 values (1,48) on conflict (id_strategy,id_account) do update set
                   id_strategy=excluded.id_strategy returning users_strategies.active, users_strategies.risk;

 active | risk
--------+------
 t      | 0.50
(1 row)
```

Comment: I presume you still need the `returning active,risk;` in there?

Comment: I wonder what implication this has for performance

Answer (score 2):

`DO NOTHING` does not apply to `RETURNING`:

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted (or updated, if an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause was used).

*[reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)*

Comment: The quoted text doesn't back up your claim - it mentions `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, but nothing about the behaviour with `DO NOTHING`. If you were right that it didn't change the behaviour of `RETURNING`, this would then imply there's something else wrong with the query in the question. Either way, this doesn't feel like it answers the question.

Comment: Some way around this imcompatible use of DO NOTHING with RETURNING to get the conflicted row columns?

Comment: @IMSoP The documentation explicitly describes the cases in which `RETURNING` applies. As a consequence, any case that is not covered must be assumed as not applicable to the context of `RETURNING`.

Comment: @Ancoron What do you mean by "not applicable"? We can split hairs about whether the quote is relevant, but I don't see how it answers the question at the top of the page. Is your answer "your question is wrong, your query should work"? Or just "yes,this is documented behaviour"? Neither seems particularly helpful.

Comment: @IMSoP I basically didn't answer the actual question and focused too much on the fact that no rows are returned (as nothing actually happened) to just explain why.